# How to use CXX flags provided by llvm-config effectively?

Tags: llvm, llvm-config

I have [a project](https://github.com/mull-project) that is built on top of LLVM. Now I am trying to come up with a CMakeLists file that would work on at least Mac OS, Ubuntu and CentOS platforms. For that I am using `/opt/llvm-3.9/bin/llvm-config --libnames x86 ...` to link my project with the libraries it needs and also I am considering to use `llvm-config --cxxflags`:

> --cxxflags        C++ compiler flags for files that include LLVM headers.

The problem, however is that `llvm-config --cxxflags` gives more flags that my library needs, specifically it adds `-O3` which I definitely don't want to be there in Debug builds of my project:

> /opt/llvm-3.9/bin/llvm-config --cxxflags
>
> -I/opt/llvm-3.9/include  -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wcovered-switch-default -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Werror=date-time -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS

It looks like `--cxxflags` gives the flags that LLVM itself was built with, not the flags it recommends me to use for my .cpp files.

This thread [[LLVMdev] Ideas for making llvm-config --cxxflags more useful](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2015-July/088815.html) has my question in the beginning of it but ends up being nowhere.

**What is the right way to pick up LLVM flags that my project might need for its files that link with LLVM?**

Comment: I suspect, things are better when you are using CMake and `LLVMConfig.cmake` module.